# How to iterate on GridLayout cells?

Tags: android

I would like to iterate programmatically over a GridLayout cells, the iteration should be applied on the layout bounds, where each cell contains an ImageButton, i understand that the layout is a mix of LinearLayout and TableLayout.

Is there a way to iterate over the GridLayout cells?

Or, what is the equivalent code to pseudo :  View v <- layout[i][j] ?

Comment: it seems like this isn't possible with the standard api